# How to pass fixed parameters to controllers in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm creating a search tool in my website, basically the main pages will call the search controller, like:

For categories:

```
/car
/pet
/food
/photo
```

For Countries:

```
/canada
/us
/italy
```

For Cities:

```
/montreal
/ottawa
/miami
/roma
```

I have a function to retrieve all possible pages slugs from: Categories, Countries, Cities,.... and I'm writing the route like:

```
foreach($pages as $page) {
    Route::get($page, 'SearchController@search');
    Route::get($page.'/search', 'SearchController@search');
}
```

For the main pages for each slug above will show a form to search and the results will be in the `$page.'/search'`

The question is how can I pass to the controller what is the page slug source: category, country or city?

Thanks for your help,

Gustavo Paixao

Comment: read docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing
you make it as a parameter in the route:

Route::get('{slug}/search', 'SearchController@search');

and then in your controller:
public function search($slug)

if you want to restrict it to proper pages you can use Regular Expression Constraints
ROUTE->where('name', 'category|country|city');

Comment: I read the laravel docs, but if I use like you said: `Route::get('{slug}/search', 'SearchController@search');` how the search method will know that is a city or country or category? Now I'm searching direct to DB but I have few tables and I need to know where.

Is it possible to pass fixed variables to the controller, like: 
`Route::get('pet/search', 'SearchController@search')->with('source','category')` or `Route::get('canada/search', 'SearchController@search')->with('source','country')`?

Comment: no you pass it as a method parameter in your controller you have the: 
`public function search()` so you add there:
`public function search($slug)` and you can use it in this method

Comment: Ok, I understood the slug usage like you mention, but if I use:
`Route::get('{slug}/search', 'SearchController@search');` and `public function search($slug)`: 

how my search method will know if the slug is a country, city or category?